# Can CSS affect submitted form data

Tags: html, css, forms, e-commerce, backend

I've recently started working as the front-end developer for a large e-commerce site. They are getting their site from a third party in a platform-as-a-service kind of way, with our access being very limited to a few front end templates, js, and css. We can't access back-end code or the header, etc.

Now, I made some quite dramatic CSS changes, because it was so sloppy, reducing the amount of css on the site by about 10k lines. Last week I got asked to revert the CSS changes because of an error which keeps appearing, preventing people from checking out. The error is clearly a server side error, that the IBM Web commerce is throwing up, showing a page with the error code and something unavailable. No one has clearly explained what the error is, only that it is preventing the form submitting properly in Chrome and that it definately the CSS, because it's now fixed since it's been reverted.

Now, I'm no back-end expert but in all the studying I've done I've never heard of CSS even being able to effect the form data, because it does nothing but visually represent the page. I suspect that someone screwed up and because I'm the new guy I'm being shot down. Previous to them saying it was the CSS causing the error, they also blamed me for it saying it was a link to the login page I had placed on the blog causing the error... The link was there before I had even started at the place...

Would really like to hear from an expert on back-end, web commerce 6, or anyone. If this is even at all feasable as an excuse.

Thanks.

eD: As mentioned in the comment, no form fields were changed to not display or be hidden via CSS. Infact all the css change did was clean up and improve the existing css.

eD2: Double checked all submit buttons and form fields on each page of the checkout process, all clearly visible and all actionable with no overlap. So that rules out overlapped elements...

Comment: If you use display none on inputs to hide them the value won't get submitted, that's about the only way that it could affect it

Comment: No, nothing like that was set or changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS cannot directly affect what gets sent in form data, but it may indirectly affect functionality and thereby cause problems that will be detected server-side. The question mentions “an error which keeps appearing, preventing people from checking out”. I have seen such things happen, in a case where CSS floats had been used to place controls and other elements. Due to CSS coding problems, in some browsers, this caused a button to be hidden entirely or partially so that it was not recognizable as a button. Somewhat similarly, it is possible to use CSS positioning so that a button seems appears but it actually stays on the background of another element with higher z-index. This could mean that a button cannot be clicked on or that clicking on what seems to be, say, a Logout button you actually click on some other button, causing something completely different.

Comment: I just double checked all submit buttons and form fields on each page of the checkout process, all clearly visible and all actionable with no overlap. So that rules out overlapped elements...

Comment: @evu, I cannot guess what might be the cause of the problem in your case (and even the problem is not really known), but I presented one possible scenario where CSS can affect functionality. To track down your problem, maybe you can test the page with selected style sheets or individual CSS rules turned off; easy to do e.g. with Firefox Web Developer Extension

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't affect form submitting if form elements aren't hidden or set to not be displayed while they are required. Css affects only how page is displayed, not WHAT is displayed, however you can set something like this:

```
selector:before {
    content: "Some text";
}

selector:after {
    content: "Some text";
}
```

But it will only put "Some text" before/after actual content, so your problem is definitely somewhere else.